# R - using rvest restrict html_node to element of html_nodes result

Tags: r, rvest

I'm using `rvest` to do webscraping - for a trial I'm scraping review scores on movies from IMDB.  For this example, I'm trying to get all the reviews and the relevant usernames from [this site](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0000001/reviews-index?start=0;count=10000000).  Note that not all reviews have a star rating - all I want is the reviews where there is a star rating.

My starting code:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

id = "0000001"
reviews = paste0("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt",id,"/reviews-index?start=0;count=10000000") %>% 
  html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//td[contains(@class, "comment-summary")]')
```

This returns a list of 11 reviews exactly as I would expect (there are 11 reviews for this movie).

When I then try to then move through this list to check for the existence of a star rating I get unexpected results.

```
reviews %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  html_node(xpath='//img[contains(@width,"102")]')
```

This yields

```
<img width="102" height="12" alt="10/10" src="http://i.media-imdb.com/images/showtimes/100.gif"/>
```

BUT the first review actually only contains:

```
<td class="comment-summary">
<a href="/user/ur0093335/"><img class="avatar" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjI2NDEyMjYyMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzM3MDk0OQ@@._SX40_SY40_SS40_.jpg" height="width="/></a>
<h2><a href="reviews?count=10000000&amp;start=0">one-shot record of a belly dancer</a></h2>

<b>Author:</b>
     <a href="/user/ur0093335/">Brian Fuller (bfuller@montreat.edu)</a>
      <small>on 12 August 1998</small>
</td>
```

The `img` returned by my code doesn't exist in the subset.  **How can I actually subset the html to do subsequent `html_node()` operations the way it intuitively should?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In xpath, `//` means search anywhere in the document. You need to anchor it with `.`:

```
reviews %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  html_node(xpath='.//img[contains(@width,"102")]')
#> NULL
```

Comment: This doesn't work - it returns only nulls.  `lapply(reviews,html_node,xpath='/img[contains(@width,"102")]')` returns a list of 11 `NULL` when there should be 7 non-null values

Comment: @Mark oops, yes, I got confused. New expression should be correct

Answer (score 0):

This feels super kludgy, but it works.

```
library(XML)
reviews %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  saveXML() %>%
  html() %>%
  html_node(xpath='//img[contains(@width,"102")]')
```

The `saveXML` function from `library(XML)` returns a character string of the subset of HTML which can then be read back in as an XML document but without the overhead of the rest of the document.

Comment: While this works for me I'd rather find a better solution that keeps a single workflow.